# How to disable cucumber message in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

How to disable this message:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          │
│ Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    │
│                                                                                   │
│ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │
│ src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │
│ Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    │
│ JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) │
│                                                                                   │
│ More information at https://reports.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber-jvm                 │
│                                                                                   │
│ Disable this message with one of the following:                                   │
│                                                                                   │
│ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │
│ src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

[image: Click here]

What steps to take?

Answer (score 4):

In the message it is saying as below:

Disable this message with one of the following:

- src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true
- src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true

For me it was disabled after doing both of the above

Comment: I find it odd that both are required to hide the message.  It very clearly says "**one** of the following". Whatever, I don't see the message anymore, so I'm happy.

Comment: Configuring only `junit-platform.properties` helped me

Answer (score 0):

create a new cucumber.properties file  under rc/test/resources/ and then add this line
cucumber.publish.quiet:true

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem here and I solved it by following the steps in the message:

1. Creating [*cucumber.properties* and *junit-platform.properties*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrN82.png) in "src/test/resources" on the Package Explorer;
2. Adding the line "cucumber.publish.quiet=true" to each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

At times the resources folder might not be there by default on eclipse , then you would need to create a folder under src/test by the name 'resources' and the create 2 sub-folders under that folder named 'cucumber.properties' and 'junit-platform.properties' and add that declaration under both.
cucumber.publish.quiet=true

Answer (score -1):

For disabling the cucumber publish message in console,[reference for console Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mlAm.png).

Create a file named "cucumber.properties" in src/test/resources file path(which by default gets created when we create a new project in eclipse). Mention `cucumber.publish.quite=true` in the properties file. That's it now you won't see that cucumber content in the console.

[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOPLh.png).

Comment: That might be true but when I did that, I got error messages about multiple factories - and if I fixed those I got errors about missing Guice modules.

Comment: It should read `cucumber.publish.quiet=true`. Works for me.