# How to make the java cucumber simplest example fully work in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

I'm new to cucumber and after trying various not fully working tutorials, I try to make this example work : https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Here is the plugin i'm using :
[image]

My version of Eclipse (wrapped into STS 4.17.1) :

[image]

To import it, I do "Import Existing maven project" on the maven project :
[image]
[image]

What works : After completing the 2 missing steps, when I run the .feature through eclipse cucumber plugin (Run as "Cucumber feature") or through "mvn test", I get :

```
Scenario: a few cukes               # src/test/resources/io/cucumber/skeleton/belly.feature:3
  Given I have 42 cukes in my belly # io.cucumber.skeleton.StepDefinitions.I_have_cukes_in_my_belly(int)
  When I wait 1 hour                # io.cucumber.skeleton.StepDefinitions.i_wait_hour(java.lang.Integer)
growl !
  Then my belly should growl        # io.cucumber.skeleton.StepDefinitions.my_belly_should_growl()

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
0m1,134s
```

What doesn't work (related to the eclipse cucumber plugin ?), 3. and 4. are the main issues :

1. In Eclipse, output starts with :

   janv. 31, 2023 3:23:38 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
   WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

This may or may not be important for the following not working items.

1b. "growl !" is displayed BEFORE the step where it is implemented :

```java
    @Then("my belly should growl")
    public void my_belly_should_growl() {
        System.out.println("growl !");
    }
```

2. In Eclipse, I'm getting this message despite all the "quiet" properties positionned in the right .properties files :

```
    ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
    │ Share your Cucumber Report with your team at https://reports.cucumber.io          │
    │ Activate publishing with one of the following:                                    │
    │                                                                                   │
    │ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │
    │ src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.enabled=true    │
    │ Environment variable:                            CUCUMBER_PUBLISH_ENABLED=true    │
    │ JUnit:                                           @CucumberOptions(publish = true) │
    │                                                                                   │
    │ More information at https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/environment-variables/      │
    │                                                                                   │
    │ Disable this message with one of the following:                                   │
    │                                                                                   │
    │ src/test/resources/cucumber.properties:          cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │
    │ src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties:    cucumber.publish.quiet=true      │
    └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

3. I'm not getting any generated cucumber report in maven "target" directory
4. If I do "Run as JUnit" in Eclipse on this project to get a visual report in the JUnit tab,  I get :

```
    org.junit.platform.suite.engine.NoTestsDiscoveredException: Suite [io.cucumber.skeleton.RunCucumberTest] did not discover any tests
```

I'd like to see the cucumber tests like this in Eclipse :
[image]

Please help me make Cucumber work in Eclipse or at least generate an html cucumber report in target.

Comment: Ok, I've completed my question.

Answer (score 3):

what I can say you regarding your q:

1. seems like the answer is here: [github issue thread](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/issues/62)

1b. I do not see in the repo you provided this example, so it is hard to say what is wrong here, I am assuming you have an extra repo with updated skeleton, so you may provide more details

2. have you checked this thread? [quite props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65011204/how-to-disable-cucumber-message-in-eclipse)
3. What I know about Cucumber reports, you need in your Runner class, you set a path to your json cucumber report:

   ```
   @CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources/functionalTests",
    glue= {"stepDefinitions"},
    plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" },
    monochrome = true    )
   ```

More examples are here: [cucumber reports](https://https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-reports/)

4. Check if your setup is correct, I think the best place for it is: [Running Cucumber Tests](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java)

Comment: Hi Maria. I've found many generic informations about cucumber too. What I'm looking here, is for someone who has a different result than me with the basic example and who can actually get a report.

Comment: But are you sure this skeleton is ready to generate such report? I do not see in their repo anything related to this, at least what I know aboutCucumber reports generation. I reviewed their RunCucumberTest.java and I did not see anything for the report generation setup, so I think you should add on your local the path and restart the test. With the "plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json" }," I think it has to be generated.

Comment: Ok, thank you this is useful. I've added "@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "json:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.json")" to respect the example syntax, and it adds the json report.